# sql server UPDATE TRIGGER doesn't fire

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

i have a trigger like below, the logic is to change FID status after fidRule status changed.

in my app, **i update 1 row in each statement,**
but i found sometimes(very rare) the trigger not firing.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerSetFIDStatus]
   ON  [dbo].[FIDRules] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 

BEGIN
set nocount on

DECLARE @ruleStatus INT
DECLARE @newRuleStatus INT
DECLARE @FIDAlertStatus INT

DECLARE @FIDId INT
DECLARE @isFIDEnabled int
DECLARE @ruleId INT

SELECT @ruleStatus = deleted.alertStatus,
    @FIDId = deleted.FIDID,
    @ruleId = deleted.id
from
    deleted 

SELECT @newRuleStatus = inserted.alertStatus
from
    inserted

SELECT @FIDAlertStatus = alertStatus,
       @isFIDEnabled= isEnabled
FROM FID
WHERE id = @FIDId


    IF @FIDAlertStatus <> @newRuleStatus
    BEGIN
        -- change FID-status by FIDRule-status
        UPDATE [dbo].[FID] SET alertStatus=@newRuleStatus WHERE id=@FIDId
    END

    IF @newRuleStatus >= 0 AND @newRuleStatus <> @ruleStatus
        UPDATE [dbo].[FIDRules] SET isAlertStatChanged=1, AlertStatChangeTime = SYSUTCDATETIME() WHERE id=@ruleId


END
```

Comment: Is your trigger enabled? Check `SELECT name, is_disabled FROM sys.triggers`

Comment: Your trigger is assuming only one row is ever updated at once.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight i update 1 row in each statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger will not be fired if the `UPDATE` statement fails or another triggers fails to execute before this trigger is fired.

One comment about your trigger itself:
You are expecting **one** records from `DELETED` which is not always correct.

Please make your trigger robust enough in case `DELETED` contains multiple records

```
-- What if deleted contains multiple records?
SELECT @ruleStatus = deleted.alertStatus,
    @FIDId = deleted.FIDID,
    @ruleId = deleted.id
FROM
    deleted
```

You can either use `SELECT TOP(1)` or make sure your trigger is able to handle multiple records from the `DELETED` list.

Comment: in my app, i send 1 time 1 update statement, should i still need change the trigger??

Comment: @Scott混合理论 It's always recommended to make sure the trigger don't cause errors. If you'll never change more than one record at the time, I recommend always the `SELECT TOP(1)` to ensure no-one can break your trigger because they did not know this restriction.

Comment: What is the query you are using to update the records? (The query which should fire the trigger, but it don't)

Comment: just: update FIDrules set alertStatus=0 /*means no_error*/ where id =xxx, but my client&i do saw [dbo].[FID] status didn't changed, and i checked logs no error was recorded.

Comment: two questions: 1: Can you reproduce the error? 2: Are you sure the `SELECT * FROM FIDrules WHERE Id=xxx` returns one record. If it returns zero, your trigger also won't update `dbo.FID`

Comment: indeed, there's a operation changed multiple row. how important  to keep code elegant!